# Custom "multicolored lines" in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to draw a graphic like the image bellow (I can use any other library if need), how can I do this using Multicolored lines?

[image]

Comment: See this:[https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-multicolored-line-py](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-multicolored-line-py)

Comment: Do not repost the same question that's already been closed.

Comment: [matplotlib make a line have multiple colors site: stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=matplotlib+make+a+line+have+multiple+colors+site%3A+stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=AOaemvKyyR04czFUjDdg9SRjqR3Xls4Vww%3A1632577557873&ei=FShPYaPbNMf5-gSz2KGAAQ&oq=matplotlib+make+a+line+have+multiple+colors+site%3A+stackoverflow.com&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgjELADECc6BwgAEEcQsAM6BggAEBYQHjoICCEQFhAdEB46BQghEKsCOgUIIRCgAToHCCEQChCgAToECCEQCkoECEEYAFCsb1iqqwZgiq0GaANwAngAgAG2AYgBiBGSAQQyMC40mAEAoAEByAEJwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjjuZ6roZrzAhXHvJ4KHTNsCBAQ4dUDCA8&uact=5)